# Соединение таблиц с условием

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server

Имеется два списка. Нужно их совместить.
Пробовал

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.name, n.name
FROM Zheni z, Nevest n
WHERE (z.vozr BETWEEN n.minvozr AND n.maksvozr) AND (z.ves BETWEEN n.minves and n.maxves) AND (z.rost BETWEEN n.minrost and n.maxrost)
      AND (n.vozrast BETWEEN z.minvozr AND z.maxvozr) AND (n.ves BETWEEN z.minves and z.maxves) AND (n.rost BETWEEN z.minrost and z.maxrost)
ORDER BY z.name, n.name
```

Что должно быть:
Алекс Анна,
Алексей Елена.

[image: Список невест]

[image: Список женихов]

Comment: можешь приложить скрипт создания таблиц? без них тяжеловато

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
        z.name AS ZheniName,
        n.name AS NevestName
FROM Zheni AS z
CROSS JOIN Nevest AS n
WHERE   (z.vozr     BETWEEN n.minvozr   AND n.maksvozr)
    AND (z.ves      BETWEEN n.minves    AND n.maxves)
    AND (z.rost     BETWEEN n.minrost   AND n.maxrost)
    AND (n.vozrast  BETWEEN z.minvozr   AND z.maxvozr)
    AND (n.ves      BETWEEN z.minves    AND z.maxves)
    AND (n.rost     BETWEEN z.minrost   AND z.maxrost)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY z.name ORDER BY n.name)
```

Comment: К сожалению, даже без учёта требований женихов и невест ваш запрос выдаёт записи с повторами)
Выводится: Алекс Анна, Алекс Елена, Алексей Анна, Алексей Елена. Должно быть Алекс Анна, Алексей Елена (или наоборот).

Comment: @МолодойБуковски сорян, поправил. Сейчас должно быть норм.
Только вот с требованиями нужно ещё отдельно поколдовать

Comment: Благодарю за наводку! С требованиями постараюсь разобраться

Comment: CREATE TABLE Nevesti (
 Gender varchar(3),
 Name varchar(15),
 Age int,
 Height int,
 Weight int,
 MinAge int,
 MaxAge int,
 MinHeight int,
 MaxHeight int,
 MinWeight int,
 MaxWeight int
);

Comment: @МолодойБуковски добавил ещё один скрипт, попробуй им выгрузить

Comment: Вы - гений! Спасибо вам огромное! Вроде весь запрос понял, кроме последней строки. Что делает OVER (PARTITION ...)?

Comment: @МолодойБуковски, создает поле с нумерацией в группе определенной условием PARTITION BY

Comment: @МолодойБуковски Последняя строка запроса нумерует все строки алфавитном порядке по n.name в рамках каждого z.name. Т.е. каждый n.name будет пронумерован от 1 до всех совпадений по условиям. А первая строка "TOP 1 WITH TIES" оставляет только 1, в данном случае, поэтому всё что больше 1 просто не попадает в результат.